# DataGridComboBoxColumn with a dropdown arrow

Tags: wpf

I want in a DatagridComboboxColumn to show a little down arrow symbolizing that this is a drop down list like in the picture below.

[image]

To achieve the above I modified the the ComboBoxToggleButton by changing the Path to:

```
<Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z">
    <Path.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" />
    </Path.Fill>
  </Path>
```

In the Popup of the ComboBox style I have left it as per default i.e:

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="Slide">
   .....                                               
    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
         <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
    </ScrollViewer>
   .....
</Popup>
```

I have named the style as **"ExpenseDescription"**

Finally the style is attached to the DatagridComboBoxColumn as an  ElementStyle as follows:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColum  ElementStyle="{StaticResource ExpenseDescription}
.......
```

This works fine.

However I was trying to modify the ComboBox Popup (drop down list) by replacing the default StackPanel with a Datagrid so that the dropdown list has multiple columns as follows(although in this example I have shown only 1 column):

```
 <Popup x:Name="Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="Slide">
 .....                                               
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Account Description"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
   .....
</Popup>
```

This only works if I attach the style to EditingElementStyle (and not to ElementStyle) and the arrow effect as described above disappears.

When I attach to the ElementStyle I get the arrow effect but all the rows are now bound to the same drop down selected item as follows:

[image]

I tried to modify the style by inserting

```
<Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
```

The effect is that the **SelectionChanged** event does not fire.

Please help me to modify this before someone directs me to another example that perhaps works.

Here is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="300"
        Height="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:DataSet1 x:Key="DataSet1" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ExpenseDetailsViewSource" Source="{Binding ExpenseDetails, Source={StaticResource DataSet1}}" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ExpenseDescriptionsViewSource" Source="{Binding ExpenseDescriptions, Source={StaticResource DataSet1}}" />
        <Style x:Key="Description" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                                          Grid.Column="2"
                                          ClickMode="Press"
                                          Focusable="false"
                                          IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen,
                                                              Mode=TwoWay,
                                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                              Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                              ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                              IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                     Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                     Background="Transparent"
                                     Focusable="True"
                                     IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                                     Style="{x:Null}"
                                     TextAlignment="Left"
                                     Visibility="Hidden" />
                            <Popup x:Name="Popup"
                                   AllowsTransparency="True"
                                   Focusable="False"
                                   IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                                   Placement="Bottom"
                                   PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                                      MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="0">

                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundColor}" />
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                    </Border>
                                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                              Background="Beige"
                                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                                              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                              ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="150"
                                                                Binding="{Binding Description}"
                                                                Header="Account Description" />
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0" />
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />
                                <!--  <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius"  Value="4" />  -->
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="ToggleButton" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TabItemHotBackground}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="SomeSelectionChanged" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource ExpenseDetailsViewSource}">

        <DataGrid x:Name="ExpenseDetailsDataGrid"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="MyDataGridComboBoxColumn"
                                        Width="*"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                        ElementStyle="{StaticResource Description}"
                                        Header="Expense Description"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExpenseDescriptionsViewSource}}"
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=ExpenseDescription,
                                                                       FallbackValue=1,
                                                                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        SelectedValuePath="ControlNumber" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the VB Code behind. The **SomeSelectionChanged** Sub is just to force the DropDown List to close.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Packaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Management
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives


Imports System.Text

Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq



Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded

        Dim DataSet1 As WpfApplication1.DataSet1 = CType(Me.FindResource("DataSet1"), WpfApplication1.DataSet1)

        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

        dsNewRow = DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDescriptions").NewRow
        dsNewRow.Item("ControlNumber") = 1
        dsNewRow.Item("Description") = "Accounting Fees"
        DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDescriptions").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)


        dsNewRow = DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDescriptions").NewRow
        dsNewRow.Item("ControlNumber") = 2
        dsNewRow.Item("Description") = "Telephone"
        DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDescriptions").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        dsNewRow = DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDescriptions").NewRow
        dsNewRow.Item("ControlNumber") = 3
        dsNewRow.Item("Description") = "Insurance"
        DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDescriptions").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        dsNewRow = DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDescriptions").NewRow
        dsNewRow.Item("ControlNumber") = 4
        dsNewRow.Item("Description") = "Travel and Entertainment"
        DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDescriptions").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        dsNewRow = DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDescriptions").NewRow
        dsNewRow.Item("ControlNumber") = 5
        dsNewRow.Item("Description") = "Water and Lights"
        DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDescriptions").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)


        dsNewRow = DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDetails").NewRow
        dsNewRow.Item("ExpenseDescription") = 1
        DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDetails").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)


        dsNewRow = DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDetails").NewRow
        dsNewRow.Item("ExpenseDescription") = 2
        DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDetails").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        dsNewRow = DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDetails").NewRow
        dsNewRow.Item("ExpenseDescription") = 2
        DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDetails").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        dsNewRow = DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDetails").NewRow
        dsNewRow.Item("ExpenseDescription") = 3
        DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDetails").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        dsNewRow = DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDetails").NewRow
        dsNewRow.Item("ExpenseDescription") = 5
        DataSet1.Tables("ExpenseDetails").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)



    End Sub

    Private Sub SomeSelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)

        Dim mycomboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
        mycomboBox.IsDropDownOpen = False

    End Sub


End Class
```

I understand what you have done. The reason why I want to use a DataGrid/ListView is because I want to sort and filter the data. With TextBlocks/TextBoxes I will not be able to sort and fiter the dropdown list.
Here is the C# code behind in case you need it. The issue is when I put the style on the **EditElementStyle** it works just fine. The problem is when I try to put the style as **ElementStyle**. Just try it and you will what I mean

```
using System;
using System.Data;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


using System.Reflection;
using System.Management;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;



namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            WpfApplication1.DataSet1 dataSet1 = ((WpfApplication1.DataSet1)(this.FindResource("dataSet1")));

            DataRow dsNewRow = dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDescriptions"].NewRow();
            dsNewRow["ControlNumber"] = 1;
            dsNewRow["Description"] = "Accounting Fees";
            dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDescriptions"].Rows.Add(dsNewRow);

            dsNewRow = dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDescriptions"].NewRow();
            dsNewRow["ControlNumber"] = 2;
            dsNewRow["Description"] = "Telephone";
            dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDescriptions"].Rows.Add(dsNewRow);

            dsNewRow = dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDescriptions"].NewRow();
            dsNewRow["ControlNumber"] = 3;
            dsNewRow["Description"] = "Insurance";
            dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDescriptions"].Rows.Add(dsNewRow);

            dsNewRow = dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDescriptions"].NewRow();
            dsNewRow["ControlNumber"] = 4;
            dsNewRow["Description"] = "Travel and Entertainment";
            dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDescriptions"].Rows.Add(dsNewRow);

            dsNewRow = dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDescriptions"].NewRow();
            dsNewRow["ControlNumber"] = 5;
            dsNewRow["Description"] = "Water and Lights";
            dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDescriptions"].Rows.Add(dsNewRow);

            //================================

            dsNewRow = dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDetails"].NewRow();
            dsNewRow["ExpenseDescription"] = 1;
            dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDetails"].Rows.Add(dsNewRow);

            dsNewRow = dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDetails"].NewRow();
            dsNewRow["ExpenseDescription"] = 2;
            dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDetails"].Rows.Add(dsNewRow);

            dsNewRow = dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDetails"].NewRow();
            dsNewRow["ExpenseDescription"] = 3;
            dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDetails"].Rows.Add(dsNewRow);

            dsNewRow = dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDetails"].NewRow();
            dsNewRow["ExpenseDescription"] = 4;
            dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDetails"].Rows.Add(dsNewRow);

            dsNewRow = dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDetails"].NewRow();
            dsNewRow["ExpenseDescription"] = 5;
            dataSet1.Tables["ExpenseDetails"].Rows.Add(dsNewRow);



        }

        private void SomeSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox mycomboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
            mycomboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your VM, where the values come from? I see nowhere `SelectionChanged` in your code. If I use ElementStyle + ComboBox in ControlTemplate all works for me, also `SelectionChanged` be called

Comment: Rekshino, I have just added the XAML and the code behind in the original question.  I have a hardcoded DataSet1.

Comment: Hmm.. I do it with c# ;) and actually I don't understand why do you try to use DataGrid in Style's PopUp? You can adjust default Style for ComboBoxItem to make DropDown multi-column

Comment: Hie Rekshino, I have provided the C# code behind in the original post. Doing it the way you have done will work but I will not be able to sort and filter which is possible with a DataGrid or a ListView. I want the user to be able to filter the DropDown list to avoid scrolling down a long DropDown list. Try it yourself  using the XAML and C# code behind provided and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Copy pasted - does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> This works fine.

Then please, do touch nothing accept putting to this Style `ExpenseDescription` a Setter for `ItemTemplate`. So you will get multirow view in the ComboBox.

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate" >
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ControlNumber}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: This will not work for me as I want to be able to sort and filter. This is why I need to use either DataGrid or a ListView.